# how to get unique(distinct) element value based on another element value from each record using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I need to get an element value based on another element value from each record.

if RECORD_TYPE='ERROR' then I have to print all the distinct (unique) ERROR_DESC values for all records under ERRORS:ERROR_DESC

Each error description should be printed in a new line.

```
<root>
<SellOutRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 1:location id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>336549R-001</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>LA</PRODUCT_LINE>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 1:location id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>336549R-001</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>LA</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>C</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 2:location id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>3X-KN73C-DB</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>HA</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 3:SO:transaction currency is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 2:location id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 3:SI:transaction document id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 5:SI:transaction currency is null or invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>5</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <InventoryRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 6:product id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>6</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>331184-B21</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0S1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>R8</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </InventoryRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 6:SO:invoiced net amount is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>6</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
</SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
</SellOutRecord>
    <SellInRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
</SellInRecord>
</root>
```

Expected output is:

```
<root>
<ERROR>record 1:location id is invalid</ERROR>
<ERROR>record 2:location id is invalid</ERROR>
<ERROR>record 3:SO:transaction currency is invalid</ERROR>
<ERROR>record 3:SI:transaction document id is invalid</ERROR>
<ERROR>record 5:SI:transaction currency is null or invalid</ERROR>
<ERROR>record 6:product id is invalid</ERROR>
<ERROR>record 6:SO:invoiced net amount is invalid</ERROR>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an example of a grouping problem? Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0? Grouping can be done in a different way in XSLT2.0, you see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. A pure "push-style" XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kErrDescByVal" match="*[RECORD_TYPE='ERROR']/ERROR_DESC"
          use="normalize-space()"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <root>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*/*" priority="-1"/>

 <xsl:template match=
 "ERROR_DESC[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kErrDescByVal',normalize-space())[1])]">
  <ERROR><xsl:apply-templates/></ERROR>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 1:location id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>336549R-001</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>LA</PRODUCT_LINE>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 1:location id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>336549R-001</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>LA</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>C</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 2:location id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>3X-KN73C-DB</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>HA</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 3:SO:transaction currency is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 2:location id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 3:SI:transaction document id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 5:SI:transaction currency is null or invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>5</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <InventoryRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 6:product id is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>6</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>331184-B21</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0S1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>R8</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </InventoryRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <ERROR_DESC>record 6:SO:invoiced net amount is invalid</ERROR_DESC>
        <RECORD_NO>6</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellInRecord>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>339112-B25</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_OPTION>0D1</PRODUCT_OPTION>
        <PRODUCT_LINE>J3</PRODUCT_LINE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>E</PRODUCT_LINE_TYPE>
    </SellInRecord>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
   <ERROR>record 1:location id is invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 2:location id is invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 3:SO:transaction currency is invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 3:SI:transaction document id is invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 5:SI:transaction currency is null or invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 6:product id is invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 6:SO:invoiced net amount is invalid</ERROR>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.
2. Use of **[`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)** to treat as equal two strings that differ only in their white space.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kErrDescByVal" match="*[RECORD_TYPE='ERROR']/ERROR_DESC"
          use="normalize-space()"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <root>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="*[RECORD_TYPE='ERROR']/ERROR_DESC"
                           group-by="normalize-space()">
       <ERROR><xsl:apply-templates/></ERROR>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
     </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <ERROR>record 1:location id is invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 2:location id is invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 3:SO:transaction currency is invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 3:SI:transaction document id is invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 5:SI:transaction currency is null or invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 6:product id is invalid</ERROR>
   <ERROR>record 6:SO:invoiced net amount is invalid</ERROR>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

Use of the XSLT 2.0 instruction **[`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)** with the `group-by` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- A key for the ERROR_DESC of all items that have an error -->
  <xsl:key name="error" match="root/*[RECORD_TYPE = 'ERROR']/ERROR_DESC" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
      <!-- Use Muenchian grouping to apply templates to distinct ERROR_DESCs -->
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="*/ERROR_DESC[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('error', .)[1])]" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- A template to handle ERROR_DESCs -->
  <xsl:template match="ERROR_DESC">
    <ERROR>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </ERROR>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```